# Can listboxItems in wp7 be reused?

Tags: ios, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am wondering if there is a way to reuse listbox items cells so you don't have to recreate the cell for every item individually?

this technique is used in iOS and as i've seen so far(by simple observasion, no tests were concluded), the performance in lists is much better in iOS then WP7 (on some-what equivalent hardware). Is this improvement due to the OS itself or is the UITableViewController(iOS) better handeled than the listbox(wp7) ?

Comment: You got it how to do it? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you will have to look more into Silverlight(Xaml) Design.
You can define all rows in the list box to be completely identical with a little code,
Xaml will be the code behind for the design.

[ListBox and Silverlight,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
I would recommend reading the above page and maybe it will give you a better feel, i develop on both IOS and WP7 and i definitively prefer what the WP7 has to offer.
It just takes a bit of knowledge on both Xaml and The language of choice for the code behind.

Comment: you mean defining a DataTemplate for the listbox? If so, are the cells not defined every time?

Comment: Yes, i just found this link here http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/   that looks more like what you explained above.

Comment: The cells, or ListBox Items can be easily recreated with a simple foreach statement.

Comment: i don't think you understand what i am asking(or that is what i think).. a listbox reuses cells when it doesn't instantiate a listboxitem for each item data that is bound to the listbox.. it practically gets an already created listbox item (that is not in the view anymore) and aplies the modifs. i don't understand what the link is about, my question was not about how to implement this, it was about what goes on behind de code.